# How to generate a specific namespace for SOAP using Java client

Tags: java, soap-client

I'm fresh to SOAP in Java. I would like to create a client that generates a similar envelope to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2009/02/ws-tra/Create</a:Action>
      <h:ChannelIdentifier xmlns:h="http://my-web-site.org/my-trans/identifiers/1.0/" xmlns="http://my-web-site.org/my-trans/identifiers/1.0/">4</h:ChannelIdentifier>
      <h:DocumentIdentifier xmlns:h="http://my-web-site.org/my-trans/identifiers/1.0/" xmlns="http://my-web-site.org/my-trans/identifiers/1.0/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" scheme="">XXXXXX</h:DocumentIdentifier>
      <h:MessageIdentifier xmlns:h="http://my-web-site.org/my-trans/identifiers/1.0/" xmlns="http://my-web-site.org/my-trans/identifiers/1.0/">d8c314a3-6add-474c-871a-e0872612beeb</h:MessageIdentifier>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:856e3d41-92ef-4332-8a36-82d98b436fb4</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://XXX.com/AP1/ResourceService.svc</a:To>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Create xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2009/02/ws-tra">
         <message xmlns="">&lt;AccessPoint.BO.Document&gt;&lt;![CDATA[Dummy Content]]&gt;&lt;/AccessPoint.BO.Document&gt;</message>
      </Create>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The main challenge here is, how to generate these specific namespaces like `a:Action` or `s:Header`. Also how to add both xmlns and xml attributes in each one. I could hard code this but is there any standard to do this?

I prefer using `javax.xml.soap.*` but if there are better library, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this draft (this requires more debugging):

```
SOAPMessage soap = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();

SOAPEnvelope envelope = soap.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
envelope.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:s"), "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
envelope.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:a"), "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");




SOAPHeader header = soap.getSOAPHeader();
header.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:xsd"), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
header.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:xsi"), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

SOAPElement actionElement = header.addChildElement("a:Action");
actionElement.addAttribute(new QName("s:mustUnderstand"), "1");
actionElement.addTextNode("http://www.w3.org/2009/02/ws-tra/Create");

SOAPElement channelIdentifierElement = header.addChildElement("h:ChannelIdentifier");
channelIdentifierElement.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:h"), "http://my-web-site.org/my-trans/identifiers/1.0/");
channelIdentifierElement.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns"), "http://my-web-site.org/my-trans/identifiers/1.0/");
channelIdentifierElement.addTextNode("4");

SOAPElement documentIdentifierElement = header.addChildElement("h:DocumentIdentifier");
documentIdentifierElement.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:h"), "http://my-web-site.org/my-trans/identifiers/1.0/");
documentIdentifierElement.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns"), "http://my-web-site.org/my-trans/identifiers/1.0/");
documentIdentifierElement.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:xsd"), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
documentIdentifierElement.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:xsi"), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
documentIdentifierElement.addAttribute(new QName("scheme"), "");
documentIdentifierElement.addTextNode("XXXXXX");

SOAPElement messageIdentifierElement = header.addChildElement("h:MessageIdentifier");
messageIdentifierElement.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:h"), "http://my-web-site.org/my-trans/identifiers/1.0/");
messageIdentifierElement.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns"), "http://my-web-site.org/my-trans/identifiers/1.0/");
messageIdentifierElement.addTextNode("d8c314a3-6add-474c-871a-e0872612beeb");

SOAPElement messageIdElement = header.addChildElement("a:MessageID");
messageIdElement.addTextNode("urn:uuid:856e3d41-92ef-4332-8a36-82d98b436fb4");

SOAPElement replyToElement = header.addChildElement("a:ReplyTo");
SOAPElement addressElement = replyToElement.addChildElement("a:Address");
addressElement.addTextNode("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous");

SOAPElement aToElement = header.addChildElement("a:To");
aToElement.addAttribute(new QName("s:mustUnderstand"), "1");
aToElement.addTextNode("https://XXX.com/AP1/ResourceService.svc");




SOAPBody body = soap.getSOAPBody();
body.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:xsd"), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
body.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:xsi"), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

SOAPElement createElement = body.addChildElement("Create");
createElement.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns"), "http://www.w3.org/2009/02/ws-tra");
SOAPElement messageElement = createElement.addChildElement("message");
messageElement.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns"), "");
messageElement.addTextNode("&lt;AccessPoint.BO.Document&gt;&lt;![CDATA[Dummy Content]]&gt;&lt;/AccessPoint.BO.Document&gt;");




ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
soap.writeTo(outputStream);
System.out.println(new String(outputStream.toByteArray()));
```

Comment: I had to change all addChildElement to be like this header.addChildElement("<ALL>", "a");

Comment: Do not mention it. Good luck!